# Python pyodbc fetch is slow

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to get some data from a MSQL Server. Works fine, except when retrieving a huge number of data: It is really slow.

I have around 4000 rows, which is not a really big number.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.1.10;DATABASE=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable')
```

I tried the following:

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
a = cur.fetchall()
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print time2 - time1
print len(a)
```

> 0:00:27.286000

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(0, 4017):
    cur.fetchone()
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print time2 - time1
```

> 0:00:21.196000

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
allIDRows = list(cur.fetchmany(4017))
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print time2 - time1
```

> 0:00:23.845000

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
a = cur.fetchmany(4017)
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print time2 - time1
```

> 0:00:24.348000

```
def ResultIter(cursor, arraysize=100):
    'An iterator that uses fetchmany to keep memory usage down'
    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(arraysize)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            yield result
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
for result in ResultIter(cur):
    pass
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print time2 - time1
```

> 0:00:31.181000

Any idea why it is so slow and what I should do to makes it fast ? (Well, if it is possible ...)

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query being run.

Comment: Correct. just added.

Comment: . . It shouldn't take 20-30 seconds to read 4000 rows into Python from SQL Server.  Your query is absurdly simple.  Possibly other transactions are slowing it down.  Possibly some of the columns are very, very wide.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @ced73?

Comment: @Justin, not really. I reduced the amount of data stored in my table building better relationship, and have been more accurate in my queries which helps. I tend to think that the pyodbc connector is just slow using Python. I am going to use another database (MongoDB) which seems to be much faster for what I am doing.

Comment: @ced73 I think you're right about the connector being slow in general. Thanks!

Comment: I've just connected to an Oracle database via pyodbc and finding a simple select from table query is unfeasibly slow. Is it just the connector, or are there any *secret* tweaks one should be employing?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking at this I've got another solution which might help.
Basically by default pyodbc uses a very old ODBC driver. It might be that your pyodbc is also set to the old driver if you've got something like this:

```py
driver='{SQL Server}'
```

To fix this I've changed it to the following in my connection properties.

```py
driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
```

Something that at first took me about 30-60 seconds to run now runs in about 5.